# Getting per-region statistics on a global

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm looking for a simple way to get the number of likes a specific region page of a global brand page.

An example is Kit Kat Japan (https://www.facebook.com/kitkat.japan) which only has the total (global) likes of ~23 million, not the per-region likes. The "talking about" value is also for the global brand (https://www.facebook.com/kitkat), not the local one.

Ideally I'd like a graph endpoint that let's me get the per-region distribution. To me, hitting /kitkat.japan on the Graph API should logically give me statistics for that region, not the global one (/kitkat).

Answer (score -1):

You can use facebook insights for this. Here's one example to use this https://seanmacentee.com/get-like-count-specific-region-facebook-page/

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  The answer is correct, although the implementation in the link is simplistic.  While for true automation OP would need to register an app and ask for the read_insights permission, using a temporary token from the graph explorer will work.